# Laravel 5 Installation in Ubuntu: laravel command not found

Tags: ubuntu, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

When I try to install laravel 5 in ubuntu, I am getting error like this,

`laravel: command not found`

I followed these steps,

`composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"`

`laravel new blog`

Comment: This worked for me: 
`composer global require "laravel/installer"`
`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Got fixed after setting path for composer vendors.So the correct step which worked is,

Download laravel installer: `composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"`

Setup PATH: `export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`

Then run command : `laravel new project-name` or `sudo laravel new project-name`

**For mac**,

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"' > ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

**Ubuntu 16.04 with latest laravel installer**

Install composer if not exists,

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '55d6ead61b29c7bdee5cccfb50076874187bd9f21f65d8991d46ec5cc90518f447387fb9f76ebae1fbbacf329e583e30') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Install laravel installer,

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

Edit environment config,

```
nano .bashrc
```

Then add,

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"
```

Then reload path config,

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

**Ubuntu 17.04 and 17.10**:

```
export PATH="~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

**Ubuntu 18.04**

```
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: This works with `$ sudo laravel new blog` but doesn't work if used without sudo like `$ laravel new blog`

Comment: I was missing the setup path (export PATH ..) Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Works for ubuntu 16 too

Comment: Thx for the Ubuntu 17.10 workaround, works on 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) too

Comment: Nice answer, but in `ubuntu 18.04` composer install laravel in this path: `~/.composer/vendor/bin`

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04: `export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: In my newly installed ubuntu 20.04 it worked well

Answer (score 57):

After searching in internet I was found for Ubuntu **17.04**, **17.10**, **18.04** and **20.04** this code that work's fine:

```
export PATH="~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

This saved my day!

Comment: Works on 18.04 too (Bionic Beaver)

Comment: where are you adding this code!

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed In my case, I'm using mac, so I have only added it to my ~/.bash_profile file in my root folder, in linux is more less the same way but the file maybe it will be .bashrc instead .bash_profile, find the .bash_profile and add it, after that you need to use the command "source .bash_profile" to read the new configuration

Comment: Works on 20.04 too

Comment: works on Mint 20.3

Answer (score 23):

If for some reasons previous Answer doesn't work, like in my situation, try this *(as a root or with sudo)*:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

and then put to the end of the file this:

```
alias laravel='~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel'
```

[Source](http://tutsnare.com/laravel-command-not-found-ubuntu-mac/)

P.S.
btw I am using

```
Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy)
PowerMac8,2
ppc64
```

Comment: That is what I did too. Still I don't get why it is not working otherwise...

Comment: make sure you run `source ~/.bashrc` to make sure it is reloaded

Comment: This works for me.  Exporting the path to `~/.profile` does not do it.  That step with `~/.bashrc` is necessary.

Comment: The esiest working solution!

Comment: stuck in this for an hour... this is the only soln that worked

Answer (score 22):

In Ubuntu 16 the path is under the `~./config` directory as shown below.

```
export PATH="~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: or you can find your composer bin by type in your ~ dir `find . -type d | grep .composer`

Answer (score 12):

Install composer

check if the composer is working by typing

```
composer
```

once the composer is installed, install laravel/installer via composer using the following command

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

after installing export the path

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then

```
 source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: dont forget to reload path config:    source ~/.bashrc

Comment: still showing command not found for me

Answer (score 9):

Open terminal and run these commands:

For zsh and bash:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"

source ~/.zshrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

For bash only:

```
export PATH=~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH

source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: the first line is in a lot of solutions, but the reloading did it for me.... source ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution after i tried many many times. First, check your actual path to the laravel installer. You need to go to `/home/(here is your name)/.config/composer/vendor/bin` ... to check if it really exist that path. In the beginning i got the 'laravel command not found' and 'bash: /home/eduard/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel: No such file or directory', so i checked if the path was correct, and it really wasn't, my path was `/home/eduard/.config/composer/vendor/bin`, i was different from any paths i found on internet. After `composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"`, the solution is:

1. go using the terminal to the path to see if it's different, until you find `/bin`. So, go to `/home/(here you put your name)/.config/composer/vendor/bin` (this is my path), and remember the path.
2. then in terminal, `cd ~`, and then `sudo nano .bashrc`
3. scroll down to the ending of the file and add:

   `export PATH="$PATH:~/.config/composer/vendor/bin"
    alias laravel='~/.config/composer/vendor/bin/laravel'`
   (!! important: keep in mind that your path may be a little bit different, make sure that the path exist like in step 1, if it's a little bit different then change it as it's your).
4. press Ctrl + X, then Y and Enter, to save changes.
5. refresh changes with `source ~/.bashrc`
6. enter `laravel` in terminal to see if everything is ok.

Keep in mind that your path may be different from any on the web, make sure that your the path it's correct, check it, and put the right one as I did. I'm using Ubuntu 16, but the solution I think is similar for any version, as long as you put your correct path.

Answer (score 4):

I followed this process installing Laravel 5 on my Linux Mint(Ubuntu-based distro): (I have written full steps to help anyone who needed simple steps.)

> // download composer 
>  curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php 
> // moved it to user folder 
> sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
>
> // download the Laravel installer using Composer 
> composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
>
> // add laravel installer to PATH 
> export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
>
> // create folder for laravel 
> mkdir /home/badar/websites/laravel
>
> // create a new project 
> laravel new blog