# Can't create a new project in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I installed the composer on my mac os and install laravel and added it to the path

so now printing the path you can see

```
 sudo nano /etc/paths
```

the result is:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/myname/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel

so laravel is there, however, when I do:

```
laravel new blog
```

I got this error:

```
-bash: laravel: command not found
```

Comment: Is `laravel` executable? Please give the result of `ls -l /Users/myname/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28597648/laravel-5-installation-in-ubuntu-laravel-command-not-found

Comment: Have you restarted the terminal since updating the path?  You'll need to do that, or source your bash file

Comment: @A.L i got this lrwxr-xr-x  1 myname  staff  28 Feb 25 23:14 /Users/myname/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel -> ../laravel/installer/laravel

Comment: @Jeff yes I did restart the terminal

Comment: @m2j i looked on that question, and adding sudo didn't help neither

Comment: Can you run `/Users/myname/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel` directly? It looks like your profile don't use `/etc/paths`. Use `echo $PATH` to see the loaded paths. It seems that `/Users/myname/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel` is a file, IIRC you have to provide the directory path (`/Users/myname/.composer/vendor/bin/`), not the file path.

Comment: @A.L this /Users/myname/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel new ElasticWebApp solved the problem, thanks! you may write an answer if you wish

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Glad to see I helped you. Did using `/Users/myname/.composer/vendor/bin/` (without `laravel`) worked for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel installation: How to place the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory in your PATH?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373188/laravel-installation-how-to-place-the-composer-vendor-bin-directory-in-your)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the result is:
>
> > /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/**bin**:/usr/local/**bin**:/usr/**bin**:/**bin**:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/myname/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel

(emphasize mine)

See how most of the paths end with `bin`, but not the one with laravel.

You have to provide the path of the directory which contain the `laravel` command, your `$PATH` should be:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/myname/.composer/vendor/bin/