# How make Laravel globally in Ubuntu

Tags: laravel

I ran into the command

```
export PATH="~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

and that worked but, this command is to be run everytime to 
run `laravel new blog` globally.
please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5 Installation in Ubuntu: laravel command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28597648/laravel-5-installation-in-ubuntu-laravel-command-not-found)